# How to prevent unique pointers from overlapping

Tags: c++, timer, unique-ptr, ctime, stdmove

I'm trying to build a timer in C++.
In my Timer class there are two Date objects that hold a `std::unique_ptr<struct tm>` pointer.
After I `std::move` the second `unique_ptr` in the second Date object in the following piece of code, it points to the same memory address of the first one, effectively making the two objects represent the same time, even though they should be different because of the *duration* offset.

```
    using namespace std;
    time_t localTime = time(nullptr);
    unique_ptr<struct tm> currentTime = static_cast<unique_ptr<struct tm>>(localtime(&localTime));
    startDate = Date(std::move(currentTime));

    time_t endTime = time(nullptr) + duration;
    unique_ptr<struct tm> timerEndTime = static_cast<unique_ptr<struct tm>>(localtime(&endTime));
    endDate = Date(std::move(timerEndTime));
```

The `Date` constructor being called is this:

```
Date::Date(std::unique_ptr<struct tm> time) : date(std::move(time)) {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use `static_cast<unique_ptr<struct tm>>` but smart pointers do not work like that. use `std::make_unique<tm>(localtime(&localTIme))`. Also the notation `struct tm`  seems to indicate you're more used to writing "C" code, but `struct` is not needed here. Follow this link [std::make_unique<T>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for more information on std::make_unique

Comment: @DanielLangr good question. It had better not be `Data(tm* time)`

Comment: Pepijn, I tried to use `make_unique` but it creates an error with `tm`'s constructor. By the way, thank you for the `struct` syntax advice.

Comment: According to cppreference, `localtime` returns a (raw) _"pointer to a static internal `std::tm` object on success"_. Why do you cast it to `std::unique_ptr`? It does not make any sense (moreover, AFAIK, it's UB). A unique pointer needs to logically own its pointee (at least with a default deleter).

Comment: Me bad I should have checked the documentation on tm. But casting to a unique_ptr is at least not something you should do. Regardless of the propeties of `std::tm`
Are you trying to get rid of raw pointers in your code (coding guidelines)?

Comment: @DanielLangr I used unique ptr's just to experiment with them. Should've read more about them and `<ctime>` before. Thank you all for your kind help

Comment: @loremol Learning C++ by experimenting is not a good idea. You will frequently end up with undefined behavior, which is extremely tricky, since the observed behavior may match that expected one.

Comment: @DanielLangr You're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unsurprising that the two objects overlap, because that is how `std::localtime` is supposed to work:

> ```cpp
> std::tm* localtime( const std::time_t *time );
> ```
>
> ##### Return value
>
> pointer to a static internal `std::tm` object on success, or null pointer otherwise.

- See [`std::localtime` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)

If you create a `std::unique_ptr` that wraps the results of `std::localtime`, you will attempt to free an object with `delete` which was never allocated with `new`, and that is undefined behavior. Write:

```cpp
std::time_t localTime = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm* currentTime = std::localtime(&localTime);
startDate = Date(*currentTime);

std::time_t endTime = std::time(nullptr) + duration;
std::tm* timerEndTime = std::localtime(&endTime);
endDate = Date(*timerEndTime);
```

Your `Date` constructor should be receiving a `std::tm` or `std::tm const&` and store it by value. If you stored a pointer, then all `Date`s would contain the same pointer to a static internal object.

##### How do I prevent unique pointers from overlapping *in general*?

This is easy to do, because `std::unique_ptr` is more or less fool-proof. As long as you:

- immediately take ownership of pointers to `new` memory, or
- exclusively use `std::make_unique`, and
- never call `std::unique_ptr::release()`

... you won't be able to accidentally make two smart pointers overlap.